# Positioning a button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, position

I'm trying to place a button just below/after an image with Jquery.

The button is just a div with some javascript:

```
<div id="printer" onclick="window.open('./print','Printer', 'resizable=yes');">
```

The point where I'm stuck: I can't get this **after** the **first** image using jQuery.

The location of the image in CSS would be:

```
.question .entry-content p img:first { }
```

Anyone who can help me out?

You can view a **SCREENSHOT** over here: - ,

You can view the source of this page: -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
$('#printer').insertAfter('.entry-content img:first');
```

---

You also have to remove the float. Ideally this should be done via CSS. If that's not possible, use this:

```
$('#printer').insertAfter('.entry-content img:first').css('float', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block` property using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
#printer { position:absolute; top:280px; margin:0; }
.qa-main { position:relative; }
```